# Read Firefox history in android (not default android browser)

Tags: android, firefox

I am new to Android and I could not find any clue to read Firefox history (not default browser) on Android programatcially. Is there any way to get Firefox history or not. If yes let me know any link or clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its is possible to get history of default browser of android. I tried this and tried to with others.

I don't think its is possible to get the history of other browser except default.

Comment: Then why you make my question negative?